# React — simplified data store rather than Redux, what are the pros and cons?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Redux is supposedly a data store for the entire application state which facilitates scalability ... be we all know that isn't the case in practice. Developers routinely refer to it as *"over-engineered"*, *"cumbersome"*, and actually a the opposite of facilitating scalability. Numerous developers have tried to come up with alternatives, Context API, an AppState class at the top level etc.

Have developers missed the point? The basic tenet of good design ... in any field, but especially CS ... is KISS.

> Keep it simple, stupid!

It strikes me that developers are missing that point. In order to streamline the data-storage process all one needs is a *"pointer"* (as it would be called in C++). You don't need Context API, Redux, or any other cumbersome library which cause more problems than they solve. React is a great library which is losing traction because of cumbersome unnecessary libraries designed to solve a problem that actually doesn't exist.

So in the context of React Apps, a *"pointer"* means simply adding a single line of code to the constructor of each class pointing to its *"this"* context, stored in an external object. To maintain nomenclature with React, I have called this method Atomic. What is Atomic? It is an external module with one line of code.

Atomic = {};

Then, in a each React class constructor, add one line of code (plus the Atomic import statement).

So for example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {x:"etc"};
}
//simply add the following line.
Atomic.MyComponent = () => this; 
}
```

Now you can access any state or function of any React class from any other React class, or indeed any external module such as a custom data-store, simply by calling its Atomic pointer.

Use state locally if you want! Keep state central in one place and use an external store! It can all be done with a few lines of code. Personally, I think react should be used how it was intended — with state stored locally — but now there are no access issues when components need to talk to each other, or any problems when an external module needs to read or write data or even call functions.

You don't need reducers, you don't need producers, you don't need consumers ... you don't need anything else.

It is just simple ES6 how it was meant to be used.

To set a component state:

```
Atomic.MyComponent().setState({x:"Atomic"});
```

To call a component function:

```
Atomic.MyComponent().increasecount(); //(or any function)
```

To load a state variable into a local variable:
"
    let x = Atomic.MyComponent().state.x;

What are the pros and cons of the above approach?

Please only reply with factual examples, not vague comments.

It has also become clear that some Redux supporters are so fanatical about Redux that they either post false statements such as "memory leak" without any factual basis, or are only here to try to close the question by voting to have it put on hold.

Comment: What's the question? Do you share your own findings? They're wrong, BTW. The next thing that should happen after you decided to KISS is to think a bit why everyone doesn't do that. The thing you're doing is similar to singleton pattern. Except that React components aren't singletons. Guess what will happen if there are several MyComponent instances around.

Comment: Good opinions but unfortunately SO is not a place to criticize or opinionate If you have any problem then do ask the question if your question is not proper atleast give rationale behind it. I am sure SO moderator will be generous enough to edit it in usable information.

Comment: For large application, requiring middleware, Redux is an awesome raw tools (you need to add sugar to it, like reduxsauce).

Comment: I believe the underlying question is - "why is the above not a good idea"

Comment: @estus >>Guess what will happen if there are several MyComponents??? Just send an index in a prop and construct the call as array, problem solved! The underlying question is, why are people so set on using Redux when simplicity is faster, better, more memory efficient etc? I think the answer was given by Kornflexx — rehortic — "Redux is awesome" — which is clearly isn't otherwise Context API and other methods wouldn't exist. At its core Redux is just a very complex wrapper for an array object. Just console.log(store.getState()).

Comment: *construct the call as array* - global state shouldn't necessarily represent a hierarchy of components, it quickly becomes unusable mess. And an array doesn't even allow for hierarchy, it's just a common grave for states. That's the problem that Redux solves with all its seeming complexity. *why are people so set on using Redux when simplicity is faster, better* - did you give this simplicity a try in a real-life projects? It's a good thing that you're enthusiastic but it's a footgun. I'd suggest to learn more about Flux/Redux and why it was designed this way before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: The purpose of the post above was to get feedback on the pros and cons of using the above method, that's the question. Please, if you are devout disciple of Redux, and feel tempted to "react" ... no pun intended ... this isn't the place. Use Redux if you want to, let others get feedback — it may benefit everyone. So far the only comments have been "spaghetti code" claims and "singleton" (incidentally Redux promotes anti-pattern (singleton global store), so, neither criticism is actually true if the above method is used carefully. It would be good to get some valid and interesting comments.

Comment: This is a completely different idea than redux and solves none of the problems it solves. It's a global variable. And redux is as about as simple a library as there is--on purpose.

Comment: Oh and also, [atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Atomicity_(programming)&redirect=no) refers to a completely different concept in programming - another name would be suited better

Comment: @Dave Newton, it isn't a global variable, it allows access to local state whether that be from other components or from a global store. Redux is a a global anti-pattern variable, Context API allows access to component state to avoid the pain of prop drilling. The above solves both those issues in one. As I have said before, SO is exactly the place to discuss the technical use of code, so it is exactly the place to post this.

Comment: @user11183528  I think you misunderstand what SO is.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a good pattern because it will encourage spaghetti code - i.e. you can access any component from anywhere and modify it. In practise, it will be very difficult to analyse and debug code paths. This is exactly the problem that Redux solves with a very clear record of global state changes (and a great tool to debug with too!).

The way I manage Redux is that I only use Redux for truly **Global** state i.e. stuff needed for intra-component communcation and global config. Local state should stay inside local components imho. Doing it this way reduces boilerplate overload and unnecessary complications.

As @estus points out, your solution gets problematic when dealing with multiple instances of components.

Comment: Well, yes, you could ... if you decided to. But you could also use that same method to access components form a single global store.  So your comment isn't a criticism of the method, but of how bad programmers may use it. Should we really be babying bad programmers? At the end of the day customers want fast efficient sites. Amazon showed that every 100ms of latency cost 1% in revenue. I think as developers we need to focus on the customer. Redux focuses on the developer ...

Comment: As I pointed out to @estus above. There is no issue with multiple instances, you merely send an index and use that index to push the call into an array. Every instance of the component can then be called in as an index of its same name. I didn't think I needed to explain that with examples because arrays are extremely simple.

Comment: @user11180371 And what would be the point of pushing unrelated component instances to an array? You can do this but what design problem does this solve? There's a bunch of unrelated instances that cannot be efficiently used because they lack the context.

Comment: The other point to mention is that Reactjs is a one-way top-down flow - designed this way to make construction and debugging simple. By bypassing this architecture, you take away the main plus of React

Comment: @jsdeveloper, yes, correct, but every React developer also knows that there are times when you need to bypass the unidirectional flow architecture. This method is just a tool for doing that. As I said above, I actually think React should be used as intended, with local state and through passing props. This method supports the way React way — by allowing developers to easily and simply bypass the structure as needed in the easiest way, and the easiest to debug way. It is easy to debug because you know which components have an Atomic contextual object associated with them and which do not.

Comment: @user11183528 Given you have 100s of unrelated Foo components, how does this help to debug them? It's the same thing as logging them with console.log, you see data but you don't know which component instance it refers to.

Comment: All array-like components in React must be indexed with a unique key, which is usually an index plus name. Take that index and set it as a state, the component is then easily identifiable. These really are simple solutions. The claimed issues by @estus are straw men, they simply don't exist.

Comment: @user11187608  I'm describing a real-world situation based on my own experience with application states (not necessary Redux or React). I assume you don't have enough experience with the subject, this seems to be the only explanation why you don't see what's wrong with it and why it can't work in a big app. You didn't even try to come up with complex real example (Todo application or so) how it could work and replace Redux. If you're interested in feedback and not pointless debates, consider writing one and posting it at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Redux provides certain levels of abstractions and a separation of concerns for application state. Redux may be unnecessary (as explained in detail in [this popular article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367)) but it also may be necessary, depending on the case. It isn't the only React state management solution but is notable one and it has a considerable ecosystem, including Redux DevTools, which is de facto tool for state debugging.

There are other state management libraries that provide a subset of functionality that Redux provides. It's possible to make use of greatly simplified implementation of Redux with React 16.8 hooks (`useContext` and `useReducer`) that don't support middlewares, or reducer composition, or any of React Redux `connect` features.

`Atomic` container doesn't solve a range of problems that is usually expected from state management. It has inborn problem with storing `this` component instance that leads to memory leaks. Once an instance is used in other place while a component was destroyed, it occupies RAM. There's no way to release an instance in `componentWillUnmount` after it was captured in and because [asynchronous rendering](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html) makes this way unsafe.

`Atomic` container is useful only to access a single instance of some component in another place; that it exposes the whole instance and its state breaks the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). At this point it isn't any better than storing data in global variable and shares most of its  This use case can be handled by context API on per component basis.

It doesn't support subscriptions for state changes and thus is useless for unidirectional data flow, unless components follow the hierarchy in which state updates will re-render child components; this shouldn't be a requirement for global state.

`Atomic.MyComponent = ...` supports only single component instance and becomes buggy in case there's more. Even if multiple instances are collected, it becomes unusable in real-world case where there can be multiple component instances and their relationship matters:

```
<Foo>
  <SortableList>
    <SortableList>
  </SortableList>
</Foo>

<Bar>
  <SortableList/>
</Bar>
```

Even if multiple instances of same component are stored, memory leaks can be much worse because there's much more instances to leak. `SortableList` instances are unidentifiable and cannot be efficiently used within the application because there's no connection with component hierarchy. Even if a hierarchy were preserved somehow, the problem is that application state shouldn't necessary replicate the structure of components and their `state`; most times it shouldn't in order to be efficient. In Redux, this is solved with abstraction layers of - reducers, `connect` mapping functions, etc.

**If component state or a part of it needs to be provided to other components regardless of their hierarchy, this can be done with context API. A value is provided by `Provider` in one place. It consumed by `Consumer` or `useContext` in another place. The whole hierarchy of components is updated when a value that they depend on is updated. This is KISS idiomatic solution that is provided by the framework.**

Comment: With regards to memory leaks, just handle the creation and destruction of components, Javascript provides ample functionality. Also, the very thing that Atomic is doing is not storing the "this" context, it provides a function to return the this context. The difference is subtle but has enormous differences. To store the this context you would write Atomic.MyReactComponent = this ... now that would potentially cause memory leaks, but that is not what is happening internally.

Comment: As mentioned above, in the simple example, yes it describes a method to access a single instance. However, it can be easily adapted to access multi-pattern instances through an array. I didn't describe this method because every JS developer should know how to adapt it. It isn't just one line of code, but it is still very simple. Context API changes the problem "How to pass a value down the component tree?" to the very similar problem "How to pass a consumer down the component tree?". Additionally it doesn't guarantee you always get the same Provider/Consumer-Pair in certain cases.

Comment: *just handle the creation and destruction of components* - it's handled by React and it's handled the way you cannot avoid memory leaks, unless you use componentDidMount instead of a constructor (and it's too late for your needs). *Also, the very thing that Atomic is doing is not storing the "this" context, it provides a function to return the this context* - it's the very same thing because `this` isn't changed as long as the function exists and it isn't garbage-collected. This method will cause leaks in React 17. You can take my word for it or go the hard way and write an app that leaks.

Comment: *it can be easily adapted to access multi-pattern instances through an array* - you can but it has no practical value. It's a collection of instances in arbitrary order that lack the context. I already gave SortableList example, how would you access innermost SortableList instance? *Additionally it doesn't guarantee you always get the same Provider/Consumer-Pair in certain cases.* - I'm not sure what you mean. *How to pass a consumer down the component tree* - you don't need to pass it, all you need is to import `Consumer` from a module where the context was defined.

Comment: "this" as an object and "this" as a function returning the context of "this" are not the same at all! And indeed I have tested it and there are no leaks! Very strange that you think there are even though I know you haven't built any projects using the above method. Incidentally your SortableList example isn't a valid example. You have 4 identical components ??? perplexing logic! You need to flesh out your example with real data to make it have any value and then I can explain the error you are making.

Comment: I think SortableList example is self-explaining. There are several unrelated lists on the page. If you push their states to an array, there will 3 instances and you won't be able to differentiate between them if you want to get their state from another place. I'm not making an error. This is real-life scenario that the approach you suggested cannot handle because it's naive and impractical by design. I tried to give a good explanation why Redux is still valid, but honestly, this discussion leads to nowhere. You just came up with random idea, called it KISS and discard any arguments.

Comment: *"this" are not the same at all* - `this` isn't changed during the existence of the function. The function is redundant and doesn't do any good. You're trying to use an approach similar to Redux getState but it was needed only because Redux state is immutable. Please, read carefully what I said regarding leaks. The problem is how asynchronous rendering will work in React 17. You won't have any leaks in current React version only if you clean up in componentWillUnmount. If you don't use it, you have leaks. And leaks are guaranteed to be in 17 because of changes in component lifecycle.